# .htaccess condition to ignore particular folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rule in place on my site to add .html to the end of URL's

```
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^/.]+)$ http://www.example.com/$1.html [R=301,L]
```

We want to have a separate blog in a directory named /blogs. I have been through many other questions on here and tried many suggestions which have not worked. Here is what i have tried so far to no avail...

```
1. RewriteRule ^blogs/.*$ - [PT] (as the first rule after RewriteEngine on)
 2. RewriteRule ^blogs - [L,NC] (as the first rule after RewriteEngine on)
 3. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(blogs) [NC] (just before the RewriteRule)
 4. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blogs (just before the RewriteRule)
 5. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/blogs/"
```

Can anyone suggest what is preventing these rules and conditions from working. They seem to work for others who have tried. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated!

-Austin

Comment: Rule number 4 is the one that *should* work

Comment: You were right rule number 4 did do the trick. Not sure why it did not work for me before but either way thanks for your help!